# Ошибка преобразования в ObjectId значения "search" по пути «_id» для модели "Product", что делать?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Хотел сделать поиск.
header.pug:

```html
form.header__block-search-content(action="/shop/search" method="GET")
      span.header-search-word Поиск
      input.header-search.header-search-show(type="text" name="search")
```

И обрабатываю его в products.js:

```js
router.get('/search', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { search } = req.body;

        console.log(search);
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Что-то пошло не так' });
    }
})
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197891/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5
Помогите решит !

Comment: заголовок вопроса никак не связан с написанным в теле вопроса

Comment: Связан, у меня ошибка - Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" at path "_id" for model "Product"

Comment: из того, что вы написали в самом вопросе, можно повторить вашу ошибку?

Comment: у меня ошибка при работе с поиском. Форма написана выше. Как я ее обрабатываю тоже написано выше. Ошибка - Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" at path "_id" for model "Product"

Comment: Приведенный код не может вызывать указанную ошибку. Хотя бы потому, что она связана с модулем mongoose, который в коде не упоминается даже косвенно.